# AWS Cognito: Restrict users to a single domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using cognito federated login with google as identity provider. The requirement is to only allow the users of my company (with domain as xxx@mycompany.com).

Any ideas on how and where to configure such rules would be much appreciated. Or kindly point me to the right documentation.

Thank you,

Answer (score 14):

I was able to achieve that with [pre-signup lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html), couldn't find a way to restrict access using configuration only.

This is my lambda function code

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log ("Trigger function =", event.triggerSource);

    // Send post authentication data to Cloudwatch logs
    if (event.request.userAttributes.email.endsWith('@mydomain.com')) {
            console.log ("Authentication successful: ", event.request);
            callback(null, event);
    } else {
        console.log ("Authentication failed: ", event.request);
        callback("can't connect to admin", event)
    }

};
```

Comment: thank you @LiorH, do you happen to know how to edit the error message (so you don't want it to be prefixed with "PreSignUp failed with error" (before your "can't connect to admin")

Answer (score 1):

You could reasonably build this validation into one of the [lambda hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-signup) that gets triggered during the user's registration/sign in flow.

Answer (score 1):

Lambda triggers only work for Cognito User Pool, not Cognito Identity Pool.

This question has been answered here: [Restrict login to Enterprise Google Domain for AWS Federated Identity Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089397/restrict-login-to-enterprise-google-domain-for-aws-federated-identity-pool)